# How to get all text between two Headings from a word Document .doc or .docx in c#

Tags: c#, dll, .doc

How can I get all the Text between two headings or a text under specific heading? Like..

**"Heading ABC"**

**"Heading XYZ"**
This is the content under XYZ heading
Test..

**"Sub heading or heading 2 of XYZ"**
XYZ heading continue

**"Heading 123"**
Content under heading 123

I want to get all the content of XYZ heading including sub heading until next heading 123 appears.. How do I find that specific heading then fetch all the content under that heading in c#? File could be .doc or .docx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void DocReader(string fileLocation,string headingText, string headingStyle)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = fileLocation;
        object readOnly = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
        string totaltext = "";
        int ind = 0;
        bool flag = false;

        int paraCount = docs.Paragraphs.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i < paraCount; i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style style = docs.Paragraphs[i].get_Style() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style;
            if (style != null && style.NameLocal.Equals(headingStyle))
            {
                flag = false;
                if (docs.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text.ToString().TrimEnd('\r').ToUpper() == headingText.ToUpper())
                {
                    ind++;
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (flag && ind>=1)
                totaltext += " \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text.ToString();

        }
        if (totaltext == "") { totaltext = "No such data found!"; }
        richTextBox1.Text = totaltext;
        docs.Close();
        word.Quit();  }
```

Comment: Taking file path, heading name to find, heading style in parameters and returning all content. If heading style is 'Heading 1' it will retrieve all content under it including sub headings / Heading 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) library to read word documents. Some sample code to get you started.

```
public string ReadAllTextFromWordDocFile(string fileName)
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        var document = new HWPFDocument(streamReader.BaseStream);
        var wordExtractor = new WordExtractor(document);
        var docText = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string text in wordExtractor.ParagraphText)
        {
            docText.AppendLine(text.Trim());
        }
        streamReader.Close();
        return docText.ToString();
    }
}
```

Play around a little.

You also want to take a look at [DocX](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX). Basic examples [here](http://blogs.quovantis.com/parsing-microsoft-word-document-using-c/). `MagicText` property of every paragraph might help you identify titles.